# EJS style template tokens in create react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

I'm making a new section on a website using create-react-app, previously I've been using node/express/ejs to render pages.

I have a server side API which returns blocks of html for the website header and footer which i inject into the pages:

```
<div id="header-container">
    <%- header %>
</div>
```

Is it possible with create react app?

Comment: it is sort of possible, though very clunky. Can you change your api to return json instead of strings?

Comment: Not quickly, what is the clunky way?